# Logarithm of a matrix in base 2?

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

Mathematica provides the built-in command `MatrixLog`, which operates on a square nonsingular matrix, but it returns the natural logarithm.

How can I find the base 2 logarithm of a matrix?

Comment: `MatrixFunction[Log[2, #] &, {{1., 1., 0.}, {0., 1., 0.}, {0., 0., 2.}}]`

Comment: `MatrixLog[m]/Log[2]`??

Comment: not related to the question, but this might be the worst function description I've ever seen.. "gives the matrix generated by the scalar function f at the matrix argument m."

Comment: There are few examples of `MatrixFunction` on this site, and an expansion of @Sektor's comment (with a better question title) might make this a useful question to keep around.

Answer (score 10):

Perhaps

```
MatrixLog[ m ] / Log[2]
```

Comment: This is generally correct?

Comment: @AimForClarity, not sure.

Comment: @Aim, yes. You can show this through the contour integral definition in my answer.

Answer (score 8):

I write this answer with the caveat that I don't have *Mathematica* version 9 or later (the versions which now have this very belated function built-in), but with said caveat being offset by knowing a [thing](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/34130) or [two](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/80368) about the function of a matrix. ;)

I'd have to agree with george's take that [the docs](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MatrixFunction.html) for `MatrixFunction[]` could probably have explained things a bit better, so here's my take.

Here's a short description:

> `MatrixFunction[]` is the *Mathematica* equivalent of MATLAB's [`funm()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/funm.html).

Hmm, that's a tad too short. How about another one?

> `MatrixFunction[f, A]` evaluates, for a given square matrix $\mathbf A$ and a given scalar-valued function $f(x)$, the contour integral $$f(\mathbf A) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint_\gamma f(z)\, (z \mathbf I- \mathbf A)^{-1}\,\mathrm dz$$ where $\gamma$ is a closed contour enclosing the eigenvalues of $\mathbf A$, and where $f(z)$ is analytic within.

(adapted from [here](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2306996))

Correct, but prolly too technical for the lot of you.

Here, then, is an informal description: if you look at however your given function is defined for scalar arguments, `MatrixFunction[]` evaluates the result of what happens if you formally replace the scalar argument with a matrix argument. For instance, if you imagine the usual Taylor series for the logarithm $\log z$, the series you get by replacing $z$ with $\mathbf A$ (and interpreting matrix powers in the sense of `MatrixPower[]`) is what is evaluated by `MatrixFunction[Log, A]` (with analytic continuation done as needed). Thus, `MatrixFunction[Log2, A]` is the function wanted by the OP. (But, as kglr notes, since `MatrixLog[]` is built-in, and presumably uses specialized, more efficient algorithms under the hood (I hope!), it is better to use this specialized function and subsequently convert the natural logarithm to a binary logarithm through the usual base-change identity.)

For people who are interested in further details, I will recommend reading *[Functions of Matrices: Theory and Computation](http://books.google.com/books?id=S6gpNn1JmbgC)* by Nick Higham; it discusses a number of algorithms for evaluation, including the standard [Schur-Parlett algorithm](http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/S0895479802410815) used internally by both *Mathematica* and MATLAB.

Comment: Nice! Thanks for the background material!

Comment: Eight years ago I implemented the integration algorithms described in referenced article by N. Higham. If that is of interest I can post the implementations. And yes -- the more specialized numerical integration algorithm for MatrixLog is faster and more precise than the one for MatrixFunction.

Comment: I'd definitely be interested in seeing them! But, I'd thought `MatrixLog[]` would use something like [inverse scaling + squaring](http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/110852553) internally; guess not.